# the use of articles after prepositions

Tags: prepositions

We say "I will contact you by letter", but we say "He was knocked down by a bus". Why is "letter" not preceded by an article?

Comment: We also speak of 'travelling by bus' because a bus is a normal mode of transport, just as a letter is a normal mode of communication. However, knocking pedestrians down is not part of the normal functions of a bus. The accident involved one particular bus.

Comment: that is why I asked why.

Comment: @LouisLiu Read up on "Zero article". Go through previous related posts on this site as well as [ell.se]. Good Luck.

Comment: "knocking pedestrians down is not part of the normal functions of a bus" !!